# Why returning Undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, hapi.js

I am working on a app where I am using Hapijs/Nodejs with AngularJS

here is the Nodejs part

```
server.route({
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/login',
  handler: function(request, reply) {
    USER: request.payload.user,
    PWD: request.payload.password,
    PLANTA: request.payload.planta,
    PLANGROUP: request.payload.plantgroup,
    START_DATE: request.payload.startDate
  }
});
```

now the Angular part

```
  .factory('LoginService', function($http, $q) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    return {
      login: function() {
        $http.post('http://localhost:8000/login', {
          user: 'USRCP_HW',
          password: 'usrcp2012',
          planta: '6000',
          plantroup: 'E10',
          startDate: '2014-11-26'
        }).success(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        }).error(function(data, status){
          console.log(data, status);
          defer.reject(data);
        });
        return defer.promise;
      }
    }

  });
```

and the Login Controller

```
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, LoginService) {

    $scope.login = function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    };

  });
```

all I need is to log the data, but I am getting undefined.

and if in the controller I do

```
$scope.login = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  LoginService.login(data).then(function() {
    console.log(data);
  })
};
```

I get this in the browser console

> OPTIONS http://localhost:8000/login
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

Comment: Match both the urls,they should be either localhost:8000 or 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because of the same origin policy constrains, I think you can use relative path for the login url.

You can't return from an asynchronous method like that

```
.factory('LoginService', function ($http, $q) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    return {
        login: function () {
            $http.post('/login', {
                user: 'USRCP_HW',
                password: 'usrcp2012',
                planta: '6000',
                plantroup: 'E10',
                startDate: '2014-11-26'
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                defer.resolve(data); //resolve the promise
                //you can't return from here as it is executed asynchronosly
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data, status);
                defer.reject(data);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

then

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, LoginService) {

    $scope.login = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    };

    LoginService.login().then($scope.login)

});
```

---

Also there is no need to create a custom promise as $http also returns one

```
.factory('LoginService', function ($http, $q) {

    return {
        login: function () {
            return $http.post('http://localhost:8000/login', {
                user: 'USRCP_HW',
                password: 'usrcp2012',
                planta: '6000',
                plantroup: 'E10',
                startDate: '2014-11-26'
            }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //you can't return from here as it is executed asynchronosly
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data, status);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

then

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, LoginService) {

    $scope.login = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    };

    LoginService.login().success($scope.login)

});
```

Comment: I am getting this: ```TypeError: LoginService.login(...).success is not a function```

Comment: @ArunPJohny - if you don't throw the exception from the .error handler - if login throws an error - you won't be able to handle the error in the next .error handler - you loose chainability. The `data` should also be returned from the success handler right ? Otherwise it doesn't end up in the $scope.login function

Answer (score 1):

Going back to your original question about CORS... In Hapi you can configure this on a route by route basis or on a global basis.

```
var server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({
    port: process.env.PORT || 3333, 
    routes: { 
        cors: true 
    } 
});
```

You can find more info here: http://hapijs.com/api#route-options

Alternatively you can serve both the client and the api from the same domain as suggested by Karanvir Kang

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a cross-origin resource problem. If you are opening the website from `http://127.0.0.1` then your script has to load/ post resources to `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost` as you doing in the login function.

Also if you are using an Apache web server, you can add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

More reading here:

- http://enable-cors.org/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

Replace http://localhost:8000/login with /login if the site on which this script is running is also hosted on http://localhost:8000.

Otherwise, you have to add cross-origin policy on your NodeJs server:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       next();
});
```

P.S: The instructions to allow CORS might be different depending on your flavor of web server.